# Protection against editing another user's profile in django

Tags: django, django-views

I have trouble with protection against editing another user's profile and I don't have any idea how to solve this issue. 
Ofcourse I know that I can do sth like this:
`<a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile_change' user.pk %}">`
or something similar.

But I don't know what i can do in situation when user write him/herself webadress. I mean situation when user with pk = 2, would write adress: "website address/profile/change/1"

Here is my models, views and urls:

```py
#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('profile/list/', views.ProfileListView.as_view(), name='profile_changelist'),
    path('profile/add/', views.ProfileCreateView.as_view(), name='profile_add'),
    path('profile/change/<int:pk>/', views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='profile_change')
]

#views.py

class ProfileCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Profile
    form_class = ProfileForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_changelist')

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'year')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_changelist')

@login_required
def profile(request):
    if Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).count() == 1:
        return render(request, 'profiles/profile.html')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('add')

#models.py
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEARS, default=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check what the user from request object is a editable user from parameters:

```py
from django.http import Http404

class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'year')
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile_changelist')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.id == self.kwargs.get('pk'):
            raise Http404
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.id == self.kwargs.get('pk'):
            raise Http404
        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```